# Saved iMessage Audio clips - Where are they stored?

Tags: ios, audio, messages, recording

A very precious audio message came my way via Messenger this evening, and the app offered for me to save it once I finished listening to it, so of course I saved it. Now I am wondering where these recordings are stored to on my device, and how I can access them in the future.

I'd like to know several things:

- how do I access these saved recordings?
- is it possible to export them via email, messenger, or other applications so that I may save them to external storage?

Running ios 15.5 on Apple Iphone 7

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By default, iMessage audios expire and are automatically deleted 2 minutes after listening to them.

So when you were prompted to save it, it wasn't actually being stored but rather just not being expired and deleted. If you scroll back on the iMessage conversation you should be able to still see it and reproduce it.

Now the weird bit.

If you now long press on the audio, you'll be prompted to save it. This  should *theoretically* send it to the *Voice Memos* App, but this **doesn't seem to be happening.**

At this point, the simplest way of storing these audios would be **through a Mac** – one on which you are logged in with the same Apple ID.

If you open the appropriate conversation in the *Messages* application, scroll to the audio, you should then be able to just **drag and drop** the audio into any folder you want.

---

By the way, iMessage's default action for audios can be changed under **Settings > Messages**, and the *Audio Messages* section.

[image]